# PHP : file_put_contents failed on directory that created by mkdir

Tags: php, .htaccess

(we use vps on centos linux, but working on subdomain)

Here is my problem:

On localhost in windows, it is just fine, but on *intenet* in linux, Why the `file_put_contents` doesn't work in directory that is created by `mkdir` ?

```
mkdir('suck', 0664, false);

file_put_contents('suck/stuck.php', 'the stick stack is stuck');
```

(The error is: failed to open stream: Permission denied in..)

Comment: is mkdir process same as file_put_contents? I mean the owner for both is same? Can you just mkdir('suck'), for testing? In addition it could be some restriction for the file extension from the hosting, can you try stuck.txt

Comment: Yes sir, the order is just like what posted above. the `suck` folder is created. But it occurs error in creating a file inside.
(function.file-put-contents: failed to open stream: Permission denied in... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories should be executable by those you want to open them. Executable bit is the lowest order bit. Try this:

```
mkdir('suck', 0755, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the example

Answer (score 1):

The execution bit needs to be turned on in a folder to be able to manipulate it's contents  by the affected user. See [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)

Comment: True! You are true sir! Thank you so so much! i use mkdir('suck', 0744, false); and works! Thank you for the links! it explains enough...